# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, async-await, backend, fetch-api, themoviedb-api

I'm doing an API tutorial and I'm catching unexpected error executing async function.

Here's the code:

```
const tmdbKey = 'here goes my API key';
const tmdbBaseUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
const playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');

const getGenres = async () => {
  const genreRequestEndpoint = '/genre/movie/list';
  const requestParams = `?api_key=${tmdbKey}`;
  const urlToFetch = `${tmdbBaseUrl}${genreRequestEndpoint}${requestParams}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch();
    if (response.ok) {
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

After executing `getGenres()`,

It's expected the `try` block to log an object to the console, with a single key: `genres`, instead, the `catch` block is logging:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
at getGenres (<anonymous>:10:28)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: You need `fetch(urlToFetch)`

Comment: the error literally tells you what the problem is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to fetch is incorrect , you need to set the required argument which is the endpoint link as first argument :

```
const response = await fetch(urlToFetch)
```

Also , it is a good habit to set the second argument which is an object that includes the method ( GET , POST ... ) , headers ( api key ... ) ...

Comment: unless you're making a plain GET request with absolutely nothing else going on :p everyone knows GET is the default method

Comment: But if you need an API key / Access token , it is mandatory to use the second argument  ;) !

Comment: of course, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

Fetch is expecting the URL to fetch from (and optional `options` object).
Try adding this:

```
const response = await fetch(urlToFetch);
```

Comment: of course, thanks for pointing this out!